# MS Access sum totals are coming in too low

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

Right now I have data with 7 fields that are categories, and 3 fields that are numeric.  This data table exists for each of 4 years, and I want it in one table with the 7 category columns, and then the 3 sum columns for each year following.  My sums are wrong and I don't know why.  Here's what I did:

`1:`  Append the category fields for all 4 years into one big table.  Run a "group by" query so we have a bunch of rows that are all unique combos of the categories.  This should contain every possible category that could pop up.  Make this into a table called "Keys"

`2:`  Run a query to sum the year 1 data.  Left Join categories in "Keys" to categories in "Year 1 table".  That should mean all rows in keys (all possible category combos) appear, and all sums should be in those rows.  However, these sums are lower than when I just sum the year 1 table.  That would mean it's leaving out records, but all categories should be present, so how could anything be left out?

Here's the query where I make the grouped keys table, which should contain all categories:

```
SELECT KEYS.age_group, KEYS.iy_group, KEYS.sex, KEYS.[BAND], KEYS.product, KEYS.class5, KEYS.ad INTO [Grouped Keys]
FROM KEYS
GROUP BY KEYS.age_group, KEYS.iy_group, KEYS.sex, KEYS.[BAND], KEYS.product, KEYS.class5, KEYS.ad;
```

Here's the query that's turning up the sums that are too low:

```
SELECT [Grouped Keys].age_group, [Grouped Keys].iy_group, [Grouped Keys].sex, [Grouped Keys].[BAND],   
       [Grouped Keys].product, [Grouped Keys].class5, [Grouped Keys].ad, Sum([OUTPUT 2014].  
       [SumOfSumOfrecord count]) AS [SumOfSumOfSumOfrecord count1], Sum([OUTPUT 2014].[SumOfSumOfface 
       amt]) AS [SumOfSumOfSumOfface amt], Sum([OUTPUT 2014].[SumOfSumOfpolicy count]) AS 
       [SumOfSumOfSumOfpolicy count]
FROM   [Grouped Keys] LEFT JOIN [OUTPUT 2014] ON ([Grouped Keys].ad = [OUTPUT 2014].ad) AND ([Grouped 
       Keys].class5 = [OUTPUT 2014].class5) AND ([Grouped Keys].product = [OUTPUT 2014].product) AND 
       ([Grouped Keys].[BAND] = [OUTPUT 2014].[BAND]) AND ([Grouped Keys].sex = [OUTPUT 2014].sex) AND 
       ([Grouped Keys].iy_group = [OUTPUT 2014].iy_group) AND ([Grouped Keys].age_group = [OUTPUT 
       2014].age_group)
GROUP BY [Grouped Keys].age_group, [Grouped Keys].iy_group, [Grouped Keys].sex, [Grouped Keys].[BAND], [Grouped Keys].product, [Grouped Keys].class5, [Grouped Keys].ad;
```

Comment: 1. Try to use 1 line for each SQL statement(`[Table].Column AS [Name] NEWLINE [Table].Column2 AS [Name] `) - it will greatly improve readability. 2. You have described a lot, but examples of original, desired and currently obtainable data will do it even better 3. You have posted the entire query. It is not enormously sized, but you can still make it more compact with the same gist-showing power - see [Minimal Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question.

Comment: how many tables do you have? how about crosstab query?

Comment: There is a "keys" table that has every category, and 4 tables of data

Comment: Seems like the schema could have been better. However, why not append the records from all four tables to a new table for a start, and just add an additional field such as 'OutputYear'? You can then create two subqueries, one for the target year, and another that crosstabs the other three years for the value you want summed, and then the final query that links the two subqueries to your 'Key'  table.